# Is it possible to have dynamic relationships in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to have dynamic relationships in eloquent?

I would like to do the following:

```
$order = Order::with('commentaar', 'commentaar.auteur')->get();
```

And in my `Commentaar` model I have this:

```
class OrderbonCommentaar extends Eloquent{
    public function auteur()
    {
        if ($this->attributes['fkauteur'] == 'personeel') {
            return $this->belongsTo('Personeel', 'id_auteur');
        } else {
            return $this->belongsTo('ContactPersoon', 'id_auteur');
        }
    }
}
```

So if the `fkauteur` column equals 'personeel' it should load the `Personeel` model and else it should load the `Contactpersoon` model.

The problem with the code I provided is that the attributes aren't filled when I call the relation.

Comment: That is not possible because when `auteur()` is invoked, there is no attribute loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look into [polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)